# Raspberry Pi 3B+ No LAN after Ubuntu Server 20.10 setup

Tags: server, raspberrypi, 20.10, headless

I've tried to flash the 64 bits Ubuntu Server 20.10 image to my Raspberry Pi 3B+, but I cannot ping or SSH into it. The Pi does show up in my ARP table, with 4 different addresses, yet none of them seem to go anywhere, everything times out.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the results of the terminal commands: `ifconfig` and: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and finally: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not have access to the device because of the problem, as it is headless.

Comment: So, I just figured out the OpenWRT overlayfs that was on the SD card somehow managed to survive a clean flash of Raspberry Pi OS. I tried flashing Ubuntu before RPOS, so I'm assuming it as been messing with that installation as well. Currently doing a low level format to get rid of the overlayfs, which worked for OpenWRT. I'm still stupefied that the partition not only survives a flash, but also affects a completely different OS.

Comment: Low-level formatting did fix RPOS, but Ubuntu still has no functional LAN. I'm assuming the current image is broken and will continue with RPOS.